# automatically connect to API once a minute and show notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have a function with notification with the time interval trigger,  which shows the notification once a minute

```
 func addNotificationWithTimeIntervalTrigger(){
            callApi()
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            print("PresentTitle",AppDelegate.titleNotification,"\(Date())")
            content.title = AppDelegate.titleNotification
            //content.subtitle = subTitle
            //content.body = body
            content.badge = 1
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats:true)
            let reguest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(reguest) { (error) in}

        }
```

But it shows only one, the old value once a minute, although the data in API has already changed. 
To see the new value, i need to press the button again, but I do not want that, i want to know how to rewrite this func that this `(timeInterval: 60, repeats:true)` includes  `callApi()` or smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NStimer for this .

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0,    
                                               target: self, 
                                               selector: Selector("addNotificationWithTimeIntervalTrigger"), 
                                               userInfo: nil, 
                                               repeats: true)
```